# One Table Query help- seems simple

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

### I have one table like this (no PK):

```
Server_ID      Job_ID
1                 A
2                 A
3                 A
4                 A
1                 B
2                 B
3                 B
1                 C
2                 C
```

I need to find out all Servers (Server_ID) that are not in all Job_ID's. 
So in this case it would be 3 and 4 (because 3 is not in JOB_ID 'C'and 4 is not in JOB_ID 'B' and 'C')

Anybody knows a good and simple solution? How could be a simple tsql query for this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MSQL from Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a query for that in two steps: first you count the number of total jobs:

```
select  count(distinct job_id)
from    yourTable
```

Then you count the `job_id` of each `server_id` and filter out those whose count matches the total jobs count

```
select  server_id
from    yourTable
group by server_id
having  count(distinct job_id) <> (
            select  count(distinct job_id)
            from    yourTable
        )
```

**Edit**

To get the missing `job_id` for each `server_id` (as requested in comments) you can create all the combinations with a `cross join`, then using `left join` with the original table you can filter only the rows that don't match

```
select  t1.*
from    (
            select  t1.server_id, t2.job_id
            from    (select distinct server_id from yourTable) t1
            cross join
                    (select distinct job_id from yourTable) t2
        ) t1
left join
        yourTable t2
on      t2.server_id = t1.server_id and
        t2.job_id = t1.job_id
where   t2.job_id is null;
```

You can see it at work [here](http://rextester.com/DYKH56183)

Comment: And if i would like to have also the JOB-ID that misses the server-id in the resultset?  e.g to 4 it misses the job  C and D

Comment: Excellent. Thank's a lot